# Нужна помощь с кросс компиляцией бинарника под разные версии Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c, docker

Задача состоит в следующем:

- Имеется простая консольная программа, без библиотек и зависимостей
- Ее нужно скомпилировать в бинарник, таким образом что его можно было запускать на разных версиях Linux (Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora т.п) в основном 64х битка.

Для решения этой проблемы пробовал использовать Holy Build Box + Docker, компиляцию статик и т.п,  но проблема остается. 
После переноса бинарника на другой Linux хост и его запуска получаю ошибку : segmentation fault .

**Очень нужна помощь в этом вопросе!**

Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111663/discussion-on-question-by-phpwork-------).

Comment: скомпилировал пример на системе с программой linux версии 4.19 (поместив его в файл `hw.c` и выполнив команду `$ make hw`), скопировал полученный блоб `hw` на машину с программой linux версии 3.10 — блоб отлично запустился (и там и там программа linux было собрана для архитектуры amd64). что-то вы не так делаете.

Comment: @PHPWork Присоединяюсь к aleksandr barakin. Структура исполняемого модуля (ELF) одинакова для всех 64-битных Linux систем. И его можно  без прооблем запускать на **любой** 64-битной системе. Аналогично для 32...

Comment: Надо больше подробностей: как именно компилируете, покажите строку апуска компилятора, что это за другой хост?